# Docker Host Security - Can container run dangerous code or change host from inside of a container?

Tags: security, docker, docker-machine

Lets say I pull a new image from a hub repository and run it without looking at the contents of the dockerfile. Can the container or image affect my host in any way possible?

Please let me know because I will be running a list of images from a user inputted image names on my server. I am worried if it will affect the server/host.

Answer (score 14):

With a default execution of an image, the answer is a conditional no. The kernel capabilities are limited, the filesystem is restricted, the process space is isolated, and it's on a separate bridged network from the host. Anything that allows access back to the host would be a security vulnerability.

The conditional part is that it can use up all your CPU cycles, it can exhaust your memory, it can fill your drive, and it can send network traffic out from your machine NAT'ed to your IP address. In other words, by default, there's nothing preventing the container from a DoS attack on your host.

Docker does have the ability to limit many of these things, including capping memory, restricting CPU's or prioritizing processes, and there are quota solutions to the filesystem.

You can also go the other direction and expose the host to the container, effectively creating security vulnerabilities. This would include mounting host volumes, especially the docker.sock inside the container, removing kernel capability restrictions with `--privileged`, and removing network isolation with `--net=host`. Doing any of these with a container turns off the protections that Docker provides by default.

Docker does have a lower level of isolation than a virtual machine due to the way it shares the kernel with the host. So if the code you are running contains a kernel or physical hardware exploit, that could access the host. For this reason, if you are running untrusted code, you may want to look into linuxkit, which provides a lightweight container based operating system to run inside a vm. This is used to provide the moby os that runs under hyperv/xhyve on docker for windows/mac.

Comment: To even protect yourself against possible kernel exploits you can have a Look at https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#/other-kernel-security-features

Comment: @BMitch great answer. I'm curious though: given that the container *is* part of the host, if the container executes `rm -rf *`, wouldn't it delete the host's file system?

Comment: @nz_21 you're in an overlay filesystem within a chroot (filesystem namespace, but most know chroot). So an rm only affects the container specific overlay working directory that you have within your filesystem namespace.